# Blue J - identifier expected message?

Tags: java, bluej

i'm writing the following code and i'm getting the error 'identifier expected' on the line

**private String class;**

```
public class Records
{
private String name;
private String class;
private int cabinNumber;

public Records(String n, String c, int cn)
{
    name = n;
    class = c;
    cabinNumber = cn;
}

public void setClass (String c){
    class = c;
}

public void set cabinNumber (int cn){
    cabinNumber = cn;
}

public String name(){
    return name;
}

public String class(){
    return class;
}

public int cabinNumber(){
    return cabinNumber;
}
}
```

can someone please explain why this is happening and what I can do to fix it?

thank you!

Comment: Don't use `class` as a variable name. That's a reserve word in Java.

Answer (score 0):

**class** is a java keyword, you cannot have a variable with this name.

Comment: thanks a lot - problem fixed.